# Suppose that $f$, $f'$ and $f''$ are positive on $\mathbb{R}$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty } f(x) = \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis

I have been trying to prove this for a quite a long time but I have been unsuccessful so far.

We need to show that for any $M>0$ there exists a $d>0$ such that $f(x)>M$ for all $x>d$ in order to show that $\lim_{x\to\infty } f(x) = \infty$.

Here's how I try to begin the proof:
Let $M>0$ be given. Let $g(x):=f(x)-M$. We need to show that there is a point $d>0$ such that $g(x)>0$ for all $x>d$. Also we have been given that $g'(x)>0$ and $g''(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus, it must be that $g$ and $g'$ are strictly increasing.

I'm not sure how to proceed after that. I tried a lot using MVT but I couldn't succeed. Hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

The function is positive, increasing and convex.

For all $x > c$ we have $f(x) > f(c) + f'(c)(x-c)$

Comment: Thanks for the hint. That helped. I completed my proof!

Comment: @AshishK: You're welcome. Good work.